# Search box servlet

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have index.jsp and I want to search through videos but whenever I search it gives me different errors and I can't get the result like it should take the user to the page where searched text exists.

> Search.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  /**
  * Servlet implementation class Search
 */
@WebServlet("/Search")
public class Search extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Search() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/HTML");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String search=request.getParameter("search");
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "MEHAK", "1234");

        PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select * from UPLOADED_FILES where filename=?");  
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            response.sendRedirect("Anime.jsp");
        }
        else{
            out.print("Sorry! Could not recognise the search!");
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e)

    {
        out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

> index.jsp

```
    <body class="page1">
<%
String u="", Login="Log In";
try{
    u=session.getAttribute("username").toString();
    if(u==null){
        Login="Log In";
    }
    else{
        Login="Log Out";
    }
}
catch(Exception e){

}
%>
    <div class="extra">
<!--==============================banner================================-->
    <header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="bg-1">
                <div class="box">
                    <h1><a href="index.jsp">Verve</a></h1> 
                    <div class="container-1">
                        <form action="Search" method="post">
                            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                            <input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Search"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is just part of index.jsp where search box is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you define a placeholder with `?` in your `PreparedStatement` you have to set it:

```
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select * from UPLOADED_FILES where filename=?");
```

change it to:

```
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select * from UPLOADED_FILES where filename=?");
ps.setString(1,"myFile.txt");
```

Comment: Beika : Thank you.. i will try to update this first.. then let you know... whether its is working or not... :)

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/] what i actually want is when i type a text to search there is dropdown of the similar ones like what happen in the provided link and on cliking of the required it should be redirected to the page where it exists. The solution you provided is helpful enough since it is atleast going to else part now before it was giving various errors.